# Save the state of some array in my activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I have a problem with handling the continuous button in my Sudoku game. THIS BUTTON works until the phone is turned on, but if I restart the phone, and try to continue playing the sudoku, the app crashes, this because I'm not saving the state of some array of integers.

This is the method onPause here, i will save the state of Activity, but not the state of my three integer  arrays,  easy[], medium[] and hard[], how can I proceed?

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Log.d(TAG, "onPause");
    Music.stop(this);

    // Save the current puzzle
    getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putString(PREF_PUZZLE, toPuzzleString(puzzle)).commit();
}
```

Comment: Re-posting your questions is frowned upon here, simply edit the information about the arrays into you previous question. Also you really should include the relevant code, otherwise we have no idea what you are doing wrong...

Comment: I edited my question OnPause inserting method code, just wondered as I do to save the status of three arrays.

Comment: There are many ways to save data, please read Android's [Data Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) guide for ideas. Choose the method with which you are most familiar. Thank your for removing the duplicate question.

Comment: I can not figure out how to do. I'm beginner with programming in Android could help me?

Answer (score 0):

Have you implemented onPause()? you should save the states in that function, and load the data on onResume()
There's a clear flowchart to show you what function is called here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html